# git pull halts and doesn't update repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am unable to take pull of my repository. When I type `git pull origin master` It seems doesn't connect with repo. Nothing happens. Here is my config file under .git folder. Any troubleshooting tips?

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Post the output of `git remote -v` (you can replace sensitive info with dummy data). Do you get any errors when you pull?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your url is similar to `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<reponame>`

Then make sure the `git clone` is working (it would also track automatically `origin/master`, which means a simple git pull will be enough to update `master`)

Finally, see if the issue persists, considering there was [some incidents in bitbucket services two days ago](http://status.bitbucket.org/).

Comment: What i observed when i push the code below 4MB it push onto origin but for more than that. its give error. Are there some restrictions on bit bucket account

Comment: @zdhim there is a limit, but only on the repo, not on the file: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repository-file-upload-size-273877699.html. Do you have some proxy on your side which might limit the output?

Answer (score 0):

In my git repos that have remotes (on github), I have some additional lines in `.git/config`;

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Try adding them and see if it helps.